# JS change border colour on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

JS noob here. Something simple, just want to change the colour of a left-border as I scroll the page. So far I have two colours working, but I need to add a third.

Here's my version - I've commented out my buggy code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWOwPz

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 200) {
      $(".main-wrapper").addClass("blue");
    } 

    //if(scroll>=400) {
    //  $(".main-wrapper").addClass("green");
    //}


   else {
     $(".main-wrapper").removeClass("blue");
     //$(".main-wrapper").removeClass("green");
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: The code that you give already changes the color, what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Use `else if` for the commented out `if` and update the first one to check scroll is under 400.

Comment: Hi @almartinez, to clarify, I want to scroll to 400  and change the bar to green, (so 3 different colours) the code I've posted above gives me 2 colours, not 3. Thanks

Comment: @GavinFriel updated my answer, your code works fine, just changed `if` for `else if`

Comment: so for portion 200 to 400 it will be red?

Comment: Worked a treat GillesC. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to make something like this

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 200 && scroll < 400) {
        $(".main-wrapper").removeClass("green");
        $(".main-wrapper").addClass("blue");
    } 
    
    else if(scroll>=400) {
      $(".main-wrapper").removeClass("blue");
      $(".main-wrapper").addClass("green");
    }
  
    else {
       $(".main-wrapper").removeClass("blue", "green");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height:1200px;
  transition:background-color 0.75s ease;
}

.main-wrapper{
   border-left: 9px solid red; 
   /* background-color: red; */
   transition:border-left-color 0.9s ease;
   min-height: 1020px; 
}

.blue {
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.green {
  border-left-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You can use if else condition with certain width and change the border color accordingly.**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll < 200) {
    $(".main-wrapper").css("border-color", "red");
  } else if (scroll > 200 && scroll < 1000) {
    $(".main-wrapper").css("border-color", "blue");
  } else {
    $(".main-wrapper").css("border-color", "green");
  }




});
```

```css
/* body {
  background-color: red;
  min-height:1200px;
  transition:background-color 0.75s ease;
} */

.main-wrapper {
  border-left: 9px solid red;
  /* background-color: red; */
  transition: border-left-color 0.9s ease;
  min-height: 1020px;
  height: 3000px;
}

.blue {
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.green {
  border-left-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add more color then you can try this solution. You can add easily more object to the `scrollColor` array.

```js
var scrollColor = [
  {
    maxScroll: 600,
    class: 'green'
  },
  {
    maxScroll: 400,
    class: 'blue'
  },
  {
    maxScroll: 200,
    class: 'red'
  }
];
    
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var mainClass;
  
  for(var i = 0; i<scrollColor.length;i++) {
    $(".main-wrapper").removeClass(scrollColor[i].class);
    if(scrollColor[i].maxScroll > scroll) {
      mainClass = scrollColor[i].class;
    }
  }
  $(".main-wrapper").addClass(mainClass);
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height:1200px;
  transition:background-color 0.75s ease;
}

.main-wrapper{
   border-left: 9px solid grey; 
   transition:border-left-color 0.9s ease;
   min-height: 1020px; 
}

.blue {
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.green {
  border-left-color: green;
}

.red {
  border-left-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One small plugin for visitors:

```js
$.fn.classChange = function(myClasses) {
    var myWin = $(window);
    return this.each(function() {
        var myWrapper = $(this);
        myWin.on('scroll', function(e) {
            var scroll = myWin.scrollTop();
            var found = false;
            $.each(myClasses, function(i, cl) {
             if( scroll<cl.s && !found ) {
                    found = true;
                    if( !cl.a ) {
                        myWrapper.addClass(cl.c);
                        cl.a = true; 
                    };
                } else {
                    myWrapper.removeClass(cl.c);
                    cl.a = false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

$('.main-wrapper').classChange([
    {
     "s": 200,
        "c": "border-red",
        "a": false
    },
    {
     "s": 400,
        "c": "border-blue",
        "a": false
    },
    {
     "s": 100000,
        "c": "border-green",
        "a": false
    }
]);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.main-wrapper {
    border-left: 9px solid red;
    /* background-color: red; */
    transition: border-left-color 0.3s ease;
    min-height: 1020px;
}

.border-red {
    border-left-color: red;
}

.border-blue {
    border-left-color: blue;
}

.border-green {
    border-left-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    Scroll down
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmmwg47y/4/) or [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmmwg47y/6/).